# 'for' statement act weird when wrapped in an 'if' statement in windows batch (.bat) file

Tags: windows, batch-file

There are two files, output.txt and test.bat. In output.txt, there's only one line, '1 2 3 4', and the content of test.bat is

```
@echo off
set condition=1

if "%condition%" == "1" (
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims= " %%a in (output.txt) do set variable=%%a
    echo %variable%
)
pause
```

run test.bat will echo nothing. but if I change it a little bit, to the following:

```
@echo off
set condition=1
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims= " %%a in (output.txt) do set variable=%%a
echo %variable%
if "%condition%" == "1" (
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims= " %%a in (output.txt) do set variable=%%a
    echo %variable%
)
pause
```

it will echo '1' twice.
Weird? Bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think either of the two scripts does what you think it does (specifically, the second script works like that only because you run it after the first).

### Why does it behave like that?

The important thing to note is that unless *delayed variable expansion* is turned on, variables will be evaluated for each command before that command is executed. This is especially critical when using `IF`, because **the whole command block inside the parens is considered as one command**.

To illustrate:

```
SET foo=
ECHO foo = %foo%
IF 1==1 (
    SET foo=bar
    ECHO foo = %foo%
)
```

The above script will output:

```
foo =
foo =
```

The reason is that the condition is equivalent to

```
IF 1==1 SET foo=bar && ECHO foo = %foo%
```

That's just one command, so variables are expanded just once before it runs (in particular, they are not expanded after the `SET` and before the `ECHO`).

This is also what happens in your script. Because `%variable%` is set *and* echoed inside the block, the `ECHO` actually operates on the value `%variable%` had before the block was entered and thus you don't see the "current" value.

### How to fix it?

#### Solving the problem with delayed variable expansion

There are two ways you can go about this. The straightforward one is to enable delayed variable expansion with `SETLOCAL` and then refer to variables with the syntax `!var!` instead of `%var%`:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET foo=
ECHO foo = !foo!
IF 1==1 (
    SET foo=bar
    ECHO foo = !foo!
)
```

The above script will output:

```
foo =
foo = bar
```

#### Solving the problem by breaking up the command block

There's also another way to do this: remember that variables are expanded once before each command (or block) is executed. It follows that if you want an expansion to occur between the `SET` and the `ECHO`, you can cause that by breaking up the block. You can do this by reversing the test with `NOT` and using a `GOTO` to skip the code that was earlier inside the "successful" branch:

```
SET foo=
ECHO foo = %foo%
IF NOT 1==1 GOTO :proceed
SET foo=bar
ECHO foo = %foo%
:proceed
```

The above script will also output:

```
foo =
foo = bar
```

## Applying the solution to your example

The two approaches translate to either this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF "%condition%" == "1" (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims= " %%a in (output.txt) DO SET variable=%%a
    ECHO !variable!
)
```

Or this:

```
IF NOT "%condition%" == "1" GOTO :proceed
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims= " %%a in (output.txt) DO SET variable=%%a
ECHO %variable%
:proceed
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug -- it's a side effect of how CMD implements variable expansion.  Raymond Chen has an article on it here:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx

Specifically, in your first example, as of when `%variable%` is expanded, it's never been set.